# Code assist in Eclipse when using library project for Android

Tags: android, eclipse

When I use library project in Android, i can not access the resources of library project from main project by writing @drawable/ ..etc . Content assist shows nothing while I press ctrl + space. Each time I should write the resource name by hand.
Is there any method to fix this issue in Code Assist.

Thanks for replies.

Comment: which version of eclipse you are using.

Comment: Have u tried restoring to defaults in 'Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced'

Comment: yes i tried but not worked. Actually main project shows its own resources but not show the ones come from library project.

Comment: Wat is the 'library project' have you added any external library, which have resources?

Comment: Yes. Can be shown here : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html . It works fine but i just want to see them in my content assist for fast coding.

Comment: I just came across this issue, even in ADT 20.0.3. It definitely slows me down and I have to second guess my code. I have opened an official issue (bug report) here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37688